# Elastic Query DSL Wont search Square Brackets within JSON field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, querydsl, kibana-6

I am trying to query a index which has a json response in one of the columns called "print_response_message" .

Sample values for this column returned are like below in 2 records.

print_response_message

```
myTestResponse string is : {
   "orderPrintResponses" : [ 
    {
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "responseCode" : "200",
    "responseMessage" : "Documents printed",
    "groupId" : "CONFIRMATION",
    "orderItemResponses" : [ {
      "status" : "SUCCESS",
      "responseCode" : "200",
      "responseMessage" : "Documents printed successfully",
      "printDocumentMappingArray" : [ {
        "pID" : "01.01",
        "documentNumbers" : [ ]
      }]
    } ]
  } ]
}

myTestResponse string is : {
   "orderPrintResponses" : [ 
    {
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "responseCode" : "200",
    "responseMessage" : "Documents printed",
    "groupId" : "CONFIRMATION",
    "orderItemResponses" : [ {
      "status" : "SUCCESS",
      "responseCode" : "200",
      "responseMessage" : "Documents printed successfully",
      "printDocumentMappingArray" : [ {
        "pID" : "01.01",
        "documentNumbers" : [ "123456789" ]
      }]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

I want to retrieve only the responses where the document numbers array is empty, in the examples I have shared above, the first one because it has the "documentNumbers" : [ ] .

I tried several approaches including matchers, terms but none of them worked.

Can someone help me out with this ? Really appreciate your help. Thanks again

I even tried escaping the [] , : etc but none of them worked. It keeps retrieving the 2nd value instead of first one. I have almost spent 2 days but couldnt get the correct query to do this.

I expect the print_response_message which has the json containing "documentNumbers" : [ ]

Comment: Can you show the query you're sending? and also your mapping, please

Comment: There is no mapping . The column :print_response_message will contain any of the messages ..i need to filter out the responses with empty array